# Random row php mysql - referencing?

Tags: php, mysql, random, reference

I'm new to php, here is my problem:
I want to select a row at random in which the same random value can be referenced later on in the page, i.e embedded in the youtube embed object. I have this working but it changes the value as the random selector is executed again (?)

```
mysql_connect("====","====","=====")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("yt")or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utube ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $results[id]; /* print youtube id */
echo '<br />'.$results[rating];
```

Can anyone help me to set up something that lets me reference the row so that I don't have different values for each part of the page where I'm using the random row from my database? Thanks

Comment: Beware that order by rand() has really poor performance.

Comment: @nick I recently changed it after reading http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/ thanks for the note!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the row into a variable which won't change.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utube ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$saved_row = $results; //don't change $saved_row later on in the script
echo $saved_row['id']; /* print youtube id */
```